# Debian Jessie unable to install GNOME extension, the native host connector is not detected

Tags: debian, gnome3, firefox, chrome, gnome-shell

I have a Debian Jessie 64bit 8.7 and 
Google Chrome Stable 57.0.2987.110.

When I visited the [GNOME Shell extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org) site, I saw the following information:

> **Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector
>   is not detected. Refer documentation for instructions about installing connector.**

On Firefox ESR  (Mozilla Firefox 45.6.0) , I got the following error:

```
ReferenceError: chrome is not defined
```

I can't install any GNOME extension because of it.
Should I install chrome-gnome-shell? 
It is in stretch and sid repositiories, not in jessie.
Should I change browsers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you should install the [GNOME Shell integration for Chrome](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation). The [Debian 9 package](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/chrome-gnome-shell)’s dependencies are satisfiable in Debian 8, so

```
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/chrome-gnome-shell/chrome-gnome-shell_8-4_all.deb
sudo gdebi chrome-gnome-shell_8-4_all.deb
```

should work (assuming you have `gdebi` installed).

You’ll need to copy all the JSON files from `/etc/chromium/native-messaging-hosts` to `/etc/opt/chrome/native-messaging-hosts` to get the packaged extension to work with Chrome; see the [troubleshooting](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation#Troubleshooting) section for details.

Comment: 3rd install this year, and I keep forgetting how to do this.

Comment: why is this not documented in the homepage, it's so stupid

Answer (score 0):

Install [chrome-gnome-shell](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation) depending on your distro and for the first time execute:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/chrome-gnome-shell --gapplicarion-service
```

After this the addon from chrome will detect the native plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This is to confirm that Stephen Kitt [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/354510/210877) above worked with Firefox 60.x.

For those not familiar with Debian Terminal command line. The package for Debian 8 Jessie can be download with your favorite browser at http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/chrome-gnome-shell/chrome-gnome-shell_8-4_all.deb

The downside of this temporary workaround is that you will not get automated updates. You need to manually update this "chrome-gnome-shell" package.

For newcomers to Debian, details steps are at https://gitlab.gnome.org/Infrastructure/extensions-web/issues/74#temporary-workaround

For other Debian versions, the packages are listed at http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/c/chrome-gnome-shell/